# How to compare and find unmatched data in json format of two json variable in php

Tags: php, jquery, json

I want to compare two variables and find the unmatched data and save it to a json in php

```
$month_name = array(

  ["months" =>"april"],
  ["months" =>"may"],
  ["months" =>"june"],
  ["months" =>"july"],
  ["months" =>"august"],
  ["months" =>"september"],
  ["months" =>"october"],
  ["months" =>"november"],
  ["months" =>"december"],
  ["months" =>"january"],
  ["months" =>"february"],
  ["months" =>"march"]

);
$test=json_encode($month_name);

$due_months=$this->dashmodel->get_due_month_by($fee_type_f);
$test2=json_encode($due_months);
test=[{"months":"april"},{"months":"may"},{"months":"june"},{"months":"july"},{"months":"august"},{"months":"september"},{"months":"october"},{"months":"november"},{"months":"december"},{"months":"january"},{"months":"february"},{"months":"march"}]

test2= [{"months":"april"},{"months":"may"},{"months":"october"}]
```

I want to get the unmatch month names of the data

Comment: We've a help here on Stack Overflow related to styling the own posts: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help ;-)

Comment: What is your exact desired result?  Do you want to maintain a 2 dimensional structure? or just a 1 one-dimensional result?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) or [array_diff_assoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php). Both of them compare array1 to the given array(s), and shows which entries from array1 are missing in them.

Demonstration: https://ideone.com/W4Cp1V

```
$month_name = [
  ["months" =>"april"],
  ["months" =>"may"],
  ["months" =>"june"],
  ["months" =>"july"],
  ["months" =>"august"],
  ["months" =>"september"],
  ["months" =>"october"],
  ["months" =>"november"],
  ["months" =>"december"],
  ["months" =>"january"],
  ["months" =>"february"],
  ["months" =>"march"]
];


$months = [
    ["months" => "april"],
    ["months" => "may"],
    ["months" => "october"]
];

$due_months = array_diff_assoc($month_name, $months);
print_r($due_months);
```

This outputs:

```
Array
(
    [3] => Array
        (
            [months] => july
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [months] => august
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [months] => september
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [months] => october
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [months] => november
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [months] => december
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [months] => january
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [months] => february
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [months] => march
        )

)
```

Comment: didnt get you,can u explain

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered=>Array to string conversion

Comment: Could you please upload your code somewhere like github or ideone so that I could take a look? Your code probably has a variable which is an array, but is being used as if it's a string.

Comment: and i want to get it in json format,because i will use it to jquery

Comment: You can always json_encode the `$due_months` and return it. But first let me take a look at your code.

Comment: If `$paid_months` is coming from the model as an array, there is no need to encode and decode it, just use as is. If it's coming as an object, use the model's correspondent method to turn it into an array, or use a loop to create an array of months *that matches the structure of the `$month_names`*.

Comment: Best do it with JavaScript: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33034768/2745485